# Moved an div item on the page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to move an item from my shop page. I moved it with google inspector tool, but i don't have any idea to move it like that in my real site.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQQ7m.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSd6M.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. In order to receive help you will need to post the code of your website. Please don't make a screenshot but copy/paste it!

Comment: Have you tried to use the [code editor in wordpress](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/edit-html-wordpress)?

Answer (score 1):

When you modify your code with google inspector, it is only to test it and see how it looks, but the changes are not saved.

If you want to save your changes, you need to open the files of your website (HTML, CSS...) directly into a code editor. Some great text editors are Sublime, Visual Studio Code or Atom.

Once you have opened your files inside your code editor, you can edit your code and save it. In your case, it seems that you would want to select the full `<div>...</div>`, cut it and then paste it a few lines below.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have more questions.